# Check if correct Google Play Service available: "Unfortunately application has stopped working"

Tags: android

Application Crashes every time I run it on my phone. Is there something wrong?  It says Unfortunately "appname" has stopped working.  I have also tried other approaches to checking for googleplay services but it always crashes. I updated my google play services and have a working google map v2 working perfectly. Any solutions to this code? It crashes on my phone running android 4.1.2 and on my AVD.

```
package com.example.checkgoogleplayproject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // Getting reference to TextView to show the status
        TextView tvStatus = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_status);

        // Getting status
        int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());

        // Showing status
        if(status==ConnectionResult.SUCCESS)
            tvStatus.setText("Google Play Services are available");
        else{
            tvStatus.setText("Google Play Services are not available");
            int requestCode = 10;
            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, requestCode);
            dialog.show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the full stack trace whenever asking about a crash.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just figured it out from my stack trace. I had to include this in my Android Manifest.

<application>
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks guys for your responses. I just figured it out from my LogCat.
I had to include this in my Android Manifest.

```
<application>
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
...
```

Comment: I don't think that fully prevents the crash.

Answer (score 156):

To check if `GooglePlayServices` available or not, Use [`GoogleApiAvailability`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GoogleApiAvailability).[`isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GoogleApiAvailability.html#isGooglePlayServicesAvailable%28android.content.Context%29), As [`GooglePlayServicesUtil`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil).[`isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil.html#isGooglePlayServicesAvailable%28android.content.Context%29)  **deprecated**.

```
public boolean isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Context context){
    GoogleApiAvailability googleApiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
    int resultCode = googleApiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(context);
    return resultCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS;  
}
```

**Update:** Check if google play service available, If google play service is not available and error is recoverable then open a dialog to resolve an error.

```
public boolean isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Activity activity) {
    GoogleApiAvailability googleApiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
    int status = googleApiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(activity);
    if(status != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if(googleApiAvailability.isUserResolvableError(status)) {
              googleApiAvailability.getErrorDialog(activity, status, 2404).show();
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: 2404? In another post I've found another number. May you explain what is that integer for?

Comment: Its activity request code, it can be any number. It will be useful when onActivityResult method get call when error get handle.

Comment: Without a library?

Answer (score 20):

I dont know where to post this but difficulty in correct workflow of google play services checking is mind blowing, I am using some custom classes, but you may get a point...

```
protected boolean checkPlayServices() {
    final int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(activity());
    if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, activity(),
                    PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
            if (dialog != null) {
                dialog.show();
                dialog.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() {
                    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                        if (ConnectionResult.SERVICE_INVALID == resultCode) activity().finish();
                    }
                });
                return false;
            }
        }
        new CSAlertDialog(this).show("Google Play Services Error",
                "This device is not supported for required Goole Play Services", "OK", new Call() {
                    public void onCall(Object value) {
                        activity().finish();
                    }
                });
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 14):

Add this method to your Splash Screen; Your app won't start at all if  you don't have Google Play Services updated or installed.

```
Dialog errorDialog;

private boolean checkPlayServices() {

        GoogleApiAvailability googleApiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();

        int resultCode = googleApiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if (googleApiAvailability.isUserResolvableError(resultCode)) {

                if (errorDialog == null) {
                    errorDialog = googleApiAvailability.getErrorDialog(this, resultCode, 2404);
                    errorDialog.setCancelable(false);
                }

                if (!errorDialog.isShowing())
                    errorDialog.show();

            }
        }

        return resultCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS;
    }
```

and call it only on resume

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (checkPlayServices()) {
        startApp();
    }
}
```

Comment: Para la versión en español pues ir a este link https://medium.com/@pedro_varela/verificar-google-play-services-7e8890d8b49a

Answer (score 10):

You set change checkPlayServices in read doc in new 2016 [google samples for google services](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/android/gcm/app/src/main/java/gcm/play/android/samples/com/gcmquickstart/MainActivity.java)

[image]

```
if (checkPlayServices()) {
            // Start IntentService to register this application with GCM.
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, RegistrationIntentService.class);
            startService(intent);
        }



    private boolean checkPlayServices() {
        GoogleApiAvailability apiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
        int resultCode = apiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if (apiAvailability.isUserResolvableError(resultCode)) {
                apiAvailability.getErrorDialog(this, resultCode, PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST)
                        .show();
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "This device is not supported.");
                finish();
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 8):

Change

```
int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());
```

to

```
int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext();
```

Comment: This method has been deprecated already. Use his `GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext())`

Answer (score 7):

As far as I know this is the minimal required code for checking for Google Play services on start of app in a splash screen like activity. Similar to Dhavel's answer, but without unnecessary code.

You can verify it works for all cases by simply passing a custom result code to the `getErrorDialog` method. All result codes are listed [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GoogleApiAvailability.html#public-int-isgoogleplayservicesavailable-context-context). It's important to use onResume since it is called after returning to the app after updating Google Play services in Google Play etc.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        if (checkGooglePlayServices()) {
            startActivity(Intent(this, HomeActivity::class.java))
        }
    }

    private fun checkGooglePlayServices(): Boolean {
        val availability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance()
        val resultCode = availability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this)
        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            availability.getErrorDialog(this, resultCode, 0).show()
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check for Play Services presence like this:

```
/**
 * Check if correct Play Services version is available on the device.
 *
 * @param context
 * @param versionCode
 * @return boolean
 */
public static boolean checkGooglePlayServiceAvailability(Context context, int versionCode) {

    // Query for the status of Google Play services on the device
    int statusCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(context);

    if ((statusCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS)
            && (GooglePlayServicesUtil.GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION_CODE >= versionCode)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And you can just pass `-1` for `versionCode` parameter.

Comment: isGooglePlayServiceAvailable is deprecated in api level 23

Answer (score 0):

2023 updated answer!

```
if (GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext()) == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){
                // available
            }else{
               // unavailable
             
            }
```