# android check location services enabled if using GoogleApiClient

Tags: android, android-service, google-api-client, location-services

I am using GoogleApiClient to get current location in Service class and while starting I want to get the status of location Service of mobile, if location service is disable then I want to show popup to enable it.

So how do I check the status of location service using **GoogleApiClient**

here is my Service class

```
public class MyService extends Service implements LocationListener,
GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener{


    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;




    private static final long INTERVAL = 1000 * 300;
    private static final long FASTEST_INTERVAL = 1000 * 200;

    public MyService() {
        super();

    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        //initialize location request
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);

        //initialize GooleApiClient
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .addApi(LocationServices.API)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
        .build();

                //code to find nearby using TimerTask
                Timer timer = new Timer();
                TimerTaskFindNearby findNearby = new TimerTaskFindNearby(getApplicationContext());
                timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(findNearby,1000,AppDataHandler.TASK_TIME);


    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        Log.d("Service","onstartcommand");
        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {


        Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        if (location == null) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        }
        else{
            onLocationChanged(location);
        }

    }



    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {


        AppDataHandler.myLocation.setLatitude(String.valueOf(location.getLatitude())+"");
        AppDataHandler.myLocation.setLongitude(String.valueOf(location.getLongitude())+"");

        //store on shared pref
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("FriendFinderSharedPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        LocationBean myLocation = new LocationBean();
        myLocation.setLatitude(String.valueOf(location.getLatitude())+"");
        myLocation.setLongitude(String.valueOf(location.getLongitude())+"");
        myLocation.setMobile(sharedPreferences.getString("myMobile", "noData"));

        //save to shared pref to make accessible from TimerTask
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString("myLocation", gson.toJson(myLocation).toString()); 
        editor.commit();

        //store location on server by using volley String request
        String url = baseURL+"userdata/savemylocation";


            //inform to activity
            sendBroadcast();
    }


    //send broadcast from activity to all receivers listening to the action "ACTION_STRING_ACTIVITY"
    private void sendBroadcast() {
        final Intent new_intent = new Intent();
        new_intent.setAction(AppDataHandler.ACTIVITY_RECEIVER_ACTION);

        sendBroadcast(new_intent);


    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.d("service", "destroy");
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult arg0) {}
    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {}


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: check google play services is available or not see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22493465/check-if-correct-google-play-service-available-unfortunately-application-has-s

Comment: that post not showing proper way

Comment: So what you want please post code what you are tried

Comment: I have added my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
            .addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);
    builder.setAlwaysShow(true);

    result = LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(mGoogleApiClient, builder.build());

    result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult result) {
            final Status status = result.getStatus();
            //final LocationSettingsStates state = result.getLocationSettingsStates();
            switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                    // All location settings are satisfied. The client can initialize location
                    // requests here.
                    //...
                    break;
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                    // Location settings are not satisfied. But could be fixed by showing the user
                    // a dialog.
                    try {
                        // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                        // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                        status.startResolutionForResult(
                                getActivity(),
                                REQUEST_LOCATION);
                    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                        // Ignore the error.
                    }
                    break;
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                    // Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way to fix the
                    // settings so we won't show the dialog.
                    //...
                    break;
            }
        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    Log.d("onActivityResult()", Integer.toString(resultCode));

    //final LocationSettingsStates states = LocationSettingsStates.fromIntent(data);
    switch (requestCode)
    {
        case REQUEST_LOCATION:
            switch (resultCode)
            {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                {
                    // All required changes were successfully made
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Location enabled by user!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                }
                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                {
                    // The user was asked to change settings, but chose not to
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Location not enabled, user cancelled.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                }
                default:
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

This will display a dialog if location is OFF

Answer (score 1):

I know this is too late but you can use this function :

```
   private boolean checkPlayServices() {
    GoogleApiAvailability apiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
    int resultCode = apiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if (apiAvailability.isUserResolvableError(resultCode)) {
            apiAvailability.getErrorDialog(this, resultCode, PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST)
                    .show();
        } else
            finish();

        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: thanks @Fadwa_Imh but what i want is to check weather the location is on or off, not the the play service

Comment: So you can use the **LocationSettingsRequest** , i'll post an a code snippet for this.