# Some devices don't receive FCM notifications

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I'm having a problem since some of my devices where I'm testing my app don't receive their notifications and it doesn't raise an exception.

The notifications comes from FCM and I'm using a custom service to show them.

MyFirebaseMessaginService.java

```
static int count = 0;
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(final RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    Log.i("remoteMessage",remoteMessage.toString());
    switch(remoteMessage.getData().get("tipo")){
        case "normal":
            notificacionNormal(remoteMessage);
            break;
        case "imagen":
            notificacionImagen(remoteMessage);
            break;
        case "imagen+url":
            notificacionImagenUrl(remoteMessage);
            break;
    }
    count++;
    //Log.d("prueba",remoteMessage.getData().get("imagen"));
}

private void notificacionImagenUrl(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setData(Uri.parse(remoteMessage.getData().get("url")));
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 100, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notif = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setContentTitle(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle())
            .setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody())
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
            .setStyle(new Notification.BigPictureStyle().bigPicture(getImagae(remoteMessage.getData().get("imagen"))))
            .build();
    notif.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notificationManager.notify(count, notif);

}
```

At the moment it only happens in a rooted device with android 6.0.1
Hope u can help me :)

EDIT:
The notification HTTP request I send:

```
"to": "/topics/general",
        "notification" : {
          "title": "title",
          "body": "body",
        },
        "data": {
          "tipo": "normal",
        }
```

Comment: Can you post your sample payload? Also, is this happening only to some specific devices or its random on all of your test devices?

Comment: @intj its only happening on one testing device and he isnt getting anithing ( it didnt even reach the first log ), and the play services are installed on the device.
Wath do you mean with a playload?

Comment: Are you sure that the `registrationToken` corresponding to that device is a recipient? I was referring to the notification payload. Or are you sending notifications thru the Firebase console?

Comment: Im sending them with topics and i tried to from the console and still do nothing, i will edit now with the http petition

Comment: Did you verify if that that specific device is subscribed to the topic you are sending it to?

Comment: @intj YEs i tried sending a global notification and still nothing

Comment: That's strange.. Is that specific device the only rooted device? Or are there any other devices rooted (which still receives the notification)?

Comment: @intj it isnt the only routed device  i tested it, and they get the notification

Comment: Did you add the MyFirebaseMessaginService in the AndroidManifest.xml ?

Comment: @DiegoGiorgini Yes. It works on other devices

Comment: Hey did you find any answer

Comment: @DevQualwebs sorry but no, it started working alone around a week on the phone but i dont know why it happens.

Comment: Is your phone an ASUS or a Mi device? Some of those devices has an app called Auto-start Manager which prevents other apps from receiving notifications. You could enable notifications from there.

Comment: i just want to tell you, same thing is happening with my live app. firebase response shows successful delivered but end user didn't get any notification. if you find any solution please tell me too.

Comment: I am also facing same problem. I can receive notification in Moto but I didn't get in Asus Mobile.Let us know if u find solution for this issue

Answer (score 1):

One of the possible reasons for this might be that some of the devices on which you're testing don't have google play services or the updated version of it. In your activity, try checking for google play services. You may use the function as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24232393/5782800):

```
protected boolean checkPlayServices() {
final int resultCode = 

GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(activity());
    if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, activity(),
                    PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
            if (dialog != null) {
                dialog.show();
                dialog.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() {
                    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                        if (ConnectionResult.SERVICE_INVALID == resultCode) activity().finish();
                    }
                });
                return false;
            }
        }
        new CSAlertDialog(this).show("Google Play Services Error",
                "This device is not supported for required Goole Play Services", "OK", new Call() {
                    public void onCall(Object value) {
                        activity().finish();
                    }
                });
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I already checked it and it doenst appears to be the problem, but somehow it appears tath dont find th fcm service :S

Answer (score 0):

it happens sometimes on low end devices. One solution is to clear the app data and cache of Google Play Services App. This work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this works, but your raw JSON body is wrong. You forgot the `{}` outside as a JSON object. Below should be your message to be sent.

```
{
    "to": "/topics/general",
    "notification" : {
        "title": "title",
        "body": "body",
    },
    "data": {
        "tipo": "normal",
    }
}
```