# How to decide on the version of google play services to use in the application when using any google play services api?

Tags: android, google-play-services

We are going to integrate **Google SignIn** (by replacing Google Plus Login). For **Google SignIn** the minimum google play services version required is **8.4**. If I go by the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating) of Google, then they have mentioned using version 9.2.1. But a lot of our app users are on slow connection networks and since 9.2.1 is relatively new, it is possible that a lot of these users will not have this update installed on their devices.  So my question is that for any api which requires google play services, which version to use?

1) The latest version (9.2.1 in the case of Google signin) - Google suggests to use the latest version because it has bug fixes. But again, if I use the latest version, then some of my users can miss this functionality. Here I can [check](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35476962/1237141) the google play services version and prompt the user for update (Not sure if all the users will update).

2) Minimum version (8.4 in the case of Google signin) - Now since this is a minimum version required, more number of users will have this version installed on their devices.

So, what is the best way to decide on the version when using any of the 
Google Play services api?

P.S. I understand that Google Play services update happens every few days, and most of the users will have the updated services. But my concern is for those users, who are on a slow network connection. Because I can achieve the same functionality by just using a lower version of Google Play Services.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is always good to go with latest versions, but if you have any other concerns you can use the older Google Play Services.

And As far as I know Google Login `com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.4.0`.

You can use play-services-auth:8.3.0 also with help of google-services:2.1.2,

```
   classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.1.2'

   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.3.0'
```

But remember you need to use all other play services should compatible with  google-services:2.1.2 and all dependencies should have the same version (8.3.0).