# android google map v2 keep crashing on gmap lstarts

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps, import

help please , my map view v2 keep crashing on startup whats wrong in this code

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
  MapsInitializer.initialize(getApplicationContext());

  // Look up the AdView as a resource and load a request.
  AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
  AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
  mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
 // adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
```

logcat error

> 19:34:46 E AndroidRuntime : FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   19:34:46 E AndroidRuntime : java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "28°23′50"
>   19:34:46 E AndroidRuntime : at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
>   19:34:46 E AndroidRuntime : at java.lang.StringToReal.initialParse(StringToReal.java:164)
>   19:34:46 E AndroidRuntime : at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:282)
>   19:34:46 E AndroidRuntime : at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:301)
>   19:34:46 E AndroidRuntime : at com.m.tnow.CompanyDetails.onClick(CompanyDetails.java:370)
>   19:34:46 E AndroidRuntime : at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5201)
>   19:34:46 E AndroidRuntime : at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21163)
>   19:34:46 E AndroidRuntime : at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
>   19:34:46 E AndroidRuntime : at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>   19:34:46 E AndroidRuntime : at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>   19:34:46 E AndroidRuntime : at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
>   19:34:46 E AndroidRuntime : at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>   19:34:46 E AndroidRuntime : at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
>   19:34:46 E AndroidRuntime : at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)

Comment: Post the log trace

Answer (score 0):

it throws GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException if GooglePlayServices not present.. may be one of the reason

Comment: i have include google play service jar in project libraries already, and in app manifest ,but it keeping crashing

Comment: check in the device where it has play services version greater than you mentioned in the gradle. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22493465/check-if-correct-google-play-service-available-unfortunately-application-has-s

Comment: how to do that in eclipse