# Get an accurate single location update on Android

Tags: java, android, location

For my app, I am trying to pull a fresh location only once to show nearby points of interest. I don't want to pull a cached location because the points of interests are displayed in order of distance from the current location, so the most current coordinates are very important

I have the following code below, but I find that sometimes it doesn't actually pull a current location (and instead seems to show the last pulled location upon requesting location again. What can I do to modify in order to pull the freshest single location in one action?

```
        mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(getActivity());

        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest.Builder(Priority.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY)
                .setWaitForAccurateLocation(true)
                .setMaxUpdates(1)
                .build();

        mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(@NonNull LocationResult locationResult) {
                if (locationResult == null) {
                    // Request update again if location is null
                    mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, this, Looper.getMainLooper());
                } else {
                    mLocation = locationResult.getLastLocation();
                    mLatitude = String.valueOf(mLocation.getLatitude());
                    mLongitude = String.valueOf(mLocation.getLongitude());
                    getClosestPOI(mLatitude, mLongitude);
                }
            }
        };

        mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback, Looper.getMainLooper());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: **Add** the following to your code:

```
/// Add Your pervious location codes here. Then
///
LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
            LocationCallback callback = new LocationCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onLocationResult(@NonNull LocationResult locationResult) {
                    super.onLocationResult(locationResult);
                    mLocation = locationResult.getLastLocation();
                    mLatitude = String.valueOf(mLocation.getLatitude());
                    mLongitude = String.valueOf(mLocation.getLongitude());
                    getClosestPOI(mLatitude, mLongitude);
                }
            };
```

**Update:** First make sure your target device has installed Google play service using [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53028701/6576302) otherwise this method (i.e. FusedLocation) will return null location and you have to use [LocationManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager) instead.

Comment: My understanding was that onLocationResult doesn't have any implementation i.e., it is an empty method, so I didn't think adding super.onLocationResult(locationResult) would have any effect. Am I missing something?