# How to check if any of google services permissions missing?

Tags: android

I've been working on an app with SMS Retriever API. But there is case when user disabled any permission of google play services and it caused the app not be able to read SMS.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22493465/check-if-correct-google-play-service-available-unfortunately-application-has-s

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if correct Google Play Service available: "Unfortunately application has stopped working"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22493465/check-if-correct-google-play-service-available-unfortunately-application-has-s)