# Check available Google Play Service

Tags: firebase, flutter

firebase_messaging gives MISSING_INSTANCEID_SERVICE error.
This is due to the fact that the device does not have Google services.

There are many solutions, but on pure android. Are there any solutions on Dart?

**Is there any way to check if Google play is available on the device without using the library?**

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use lib, you can use method channel to call native code check,
refer native code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22493465/check-if-correct-google-play-service-available-unfortunately-application-has-s)